# How get a list of element using sharedpreferences from specify key?

Tags: java, android

```
SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savedSearches.edit();
 preferencesEditor.putString(key, "element1");
 preferencesEditor.putString(key2, "element2");
 preferencesEditor.putString(key, "element3");
 preferencesEditor.putString(key2, "element4");
```

How get only elements from key2 or key?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `putString` to store one `String` for each key. So when you write

```
preferencesEditor.putString(key, "element1");
preferencesEditor.putString(key2, "element2");
preferencesEditor.putString(key, "element3");
preferencesEditor.putString(key2, "element4");
```

the first two lines are redundant.

If you want to store multiple `String`s for each key, you can use `putStringSet`. It is not possible to store a `List` of `String`s for one key.